# Minimizer for distance from point A to point B constrained by quadric surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Having a strange issue with a Lagrange Multiplier problem. I'm trying to find the point on the quadric surface $x^2-y^2=1$ closest to the point (1,0,0).

When I do the Lagrange equations, I get $2x-2=2xλ$ and $2y=-2yλ$. But from here, I get $λ =-1$ from the Y Lagrange and $1-1/x=λ$ from the X Lagrange. This ends up with $x=1/2$ and $y$ is an imaginary number.

I keep checking my math, but I can't find the mistakes. Does LaGrange not work for this problem? The answer is obvious after a while, the point (1,0,0) fulfills $x^2-y^2=1$. But I'm more interested in where my error is.

Answer (score 1):

Your quadric surface is independent of $z$. As such, you can ignore all consideration of $z$, and solve the problem in the $x$-$y$ plane ($z=0$).

[image]

(But I think you've mis-stated the problem... so you should check on that.)

Answer (score 0):

The optimality conditions are:
$x (1 - \lambda) = 0$, $y (1 + \lambda) = 0$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 1$.
$\lambda = -1$ doesn't give you a real solution, but you should check the other cases.